# I can't connect to MangoDB which is on VPS server by MongoDB Campass

Tags: node.js, mongodb, server, centos, vps

How can I connect to a Mongo database through Mongo Compass? I connected to the server with `SSH` and typed `mongosh` and it gave me this link: `mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?directConnection=true&serverSelectionTimeoutMS=2000&appName=mongosh+1.7.1`

Also, when I execute the `show dbs` command, it does not display any database except the system databases!

I would like to know what exactly is happening and how to connect with `mongoDB Campass` to the database that is on the `VPS` server?

**NOTE:**  The `operating system` installed on the VPS is `CentOS7`.

Thank you for your guidance

Comment: Is the firewall open for incoming traffic on port 27017?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Yes.

Comment: Just enter the IP-Address of your server in Compass, then it should work.

Comment: it give this error `connect ETIMEDOUT server.ip.address:27017`

Comment: Also it has this warning `TLS/SSL is disabled. If possible, enable TLS/SSL to avoid security vulnerabilities.` . should I enable it?

Comment: Yes, TLS/SSL should be enabled but this would be the second step, first try without. The error message `connect ETIMEDOUT` usually indicates either network connection is blocked or mongod is not started. Maybe the local firewall on the server still blocks the traffic. Try with `curl --connect-timeout 10 --silent --show-error server.ip.address:27017`